# Remplazar una plantilla con otra en nodejs

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express, jade, ecmascript-2015

Tengo una duda..
Implemento un botón de cerrar sesión.

Ya cree el evento y todo bien. Pero como le puedo hacer para decirle al servidor que me mande la pagina de bienvenida.

Uso servidor nodejs.
Y en el front javascript...

La pagina de bienvenida es una plantilla pug

Answer (score 0):

Puedes redirigir a la pantalla de bienvenida luego de pegarle al endpoint que hace el logout.

```
app.get('/logout', function(req, res, next) {
   // acá haces la lógica de logout, como matar la sesión
   res.redirect('/bienvenida');
});

app.get('/bienvenida', function(req, res, next) {
   res.render('bienvenida');
});
```